# Calculating and Adding Several Columns to SQL results in only 1 row

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, calculated-columns

I have a SQLite DB that has a table which has the following values:

| id | Broker | Stock | Long_Short | Stock_Price | Shares_Owned |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | AMC | Long | 14.76 | 8 |
| 2 | 1 | MSFT | Short | 282.36 | 8 |
| 3 | 1 | AAPL | Short | 161.42 | 8 |
| 4 | 1 | TSLA | Short | 922.672 | 8 |
| 5 | 1 | FB | Long | 215.48 | 8 |
| 6 | 1 | XOM | Short | 91.72 | 8 |
| 7 | 1 | BAC | Long | 37.8 | 8 |
| 8 | 1 | KO | Short | 64.745 | 8 |
| 9 | 1 | DIS | Long | 114.42 | 8 |
| 10 | 1 | VZ | Short | 48.02 | 8 |
| 11 | 2 | AMC | Long | 14.76 | 9 |
| 12 | 3 | AMC | Short | 14.76 | 10 |

I need to be able to query the table to get the following result:

**Stock | Aggregate_Value | Total_Added_Up | "Exposure %"**

- Aggregate_Value = Stock_Price * Shares_Owned
- Total_Added_Up = The sum of all Aggregate_Value's.
- "Exposure %" = ((Aggregate_Value / Total_Added_Up) * 100)

`select Stock, SUM(Total_Value) AS Aggregate_Value from (select Stock, Stock_Price*Shares_Owned AS Total_Value from Trades ) group by Stock;`

The above query gives me a good Aggregate_Value column.

I can get the Total_Added_Up value by doing:

```
    from (select Stock, SUM(Total_Value) AS Aggregate_Value
        from (select Stock, Stock_Price*Shares_Owned AS Total_Value 
            from Trades)
            group by Stock);
```

I tried the following query to combine Aggregate_Value Total_Added_Up, and "Exposure %":

```
    from (select Stock, Aggregate_Value, SUM(Aggregate_Value) AS Total_Added_Up
        from (select Stock, SUM(Total_Value) AS Aggregate_Value
            from (select Stock, Stock_Price*Shares_Owned AS Total_Value 
                from Trades)
                group by Stock));
```

The above query will give me the format **Stock | Aggregate_Value | Total_Added_Up | "Exposure %"**, but it is only one row when there should be a row for every Stock.

The output I am getting looks like the following.

| Stock | Aggregate_Value | Total_Added_Up | Shares_Owned |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| XOM | 733.76 | 15907.616 | 4.6126333 |

The output I am expecting is.

| Stock | Aggregate_Value | Total_Added_Up | Shares_Owned |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AMC | 733.76 | 15907.616 | 4.6126333 |
| MSFT | (To_Calculate) | 15907.616 | (To_Calculate) |
| AAPL | (To_Calculate) | 15907.616 | (To_Calculate) |
| TSLA | (To_Calculate) | 15907.616 | (To_Calculate) |

And so on with the rest of the listed Stocks.

Am I overcomplicating this or is there an easier way to get to my solution?

Comment: Post sample data and expected results in text format and not images to clarify what you want.

Answer (score 0):

`select Stock, SUM(Total_Value) AS Aggregate_Value from (select Stock, Stock_Price*Shares_Owned AS Total_Value from Trades group by Stock;)`

Can be converted to

```
SELECT Stock, 
     SUM(Stock_Price*Shares_Owned) AS Aggregate_Value 
     FROM Trades 
GROUP BY Stock;
```

What you're doing is correct, just make it look cleaner, it'll help you read  and debug it.

This will give you the Total_Added_Up value. It's only a variable. I am not familiar with SQLite DB, but it might be difficult to use a variable there.

```
SELECT SUM(Stock_Price*Shares_Owned) 
FROM Trades
```

So join those two tables in a new `select`  and you have all of the needed values for the Exposure value.  Just make sure to not divide by 0 in your formula

Comment: The syntax might be wrong due to me not knowing SQLite DB, but if you search for the conversions from mssql, it should come up

Comment: Thank you. I have changed my code slightly and now have the following query, SELECT Stock, Aggregate_Value, Total_Added_Up
FROM
(SELECT Stock, SUM(Stock_Price*Shares_Owned) AS Aggregate_Value FROM Trades GROUP BY Stock)
INNER JOIN
(SELECT SUM(Stock_Price*Shares_Owned) AS Total_Added_Up FROM Trades)  How can I find the "Exposure %" from this the best way?

Comment: ( Aggregate_Value/ Total_Added_Up ) / 100 in the select statement @nbk  also shows another way to do it

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in one seLect by joning the total sum

I also rounded it  uop to 2 digits, so that ot wouldn't look to wild, but you can increase the numbers of digits or get rod of the rounding

> ```
> SELECT
> `Stock`,
> SUM(`Stock_Price` * `Shares_Owned`)
> ,Total_Added_Up, ROUND((SUM(`Stock_Price` * `Shares_Owned`) / Total_Added_Up) * 100,2) as 'Exposure %'
> FROM stocks CROSS JOIN (SELECT SUM(`Stock_Price` * `Shares_Owned`) Total_Added_Up  FROM stocks) as t1
> GROUP BY `Stock`
> ```
>
> ```
> Stock | SUM(`Stock_Price` * `Shares_Owned`) | Total_Added_Up | Exposure %
> :---- | ----------------------------------: | -------------: | ---------:
> AAPL  |                             1291.36 |      15907.616 |       8.12
> AMC   |                              398.52 |      15907.616 |       2.51
> BAC   |                               302.4 |      15907.616 |        1.9
> DIS   |                              915.36 |      15907.616 |       5.75
> FB    |                             1723.84 |      15907.616 |      10.84
> KO    |                              517.96 |      15907.616 |       3.26
> MSFT  |                             2258.88 |      15907.616 |       14.2
> TSLA  |                            7381.376 |      15907.616 |       46.4
> VZ    |                              384.16 |      15907.616 |       2.41
> XOM   |                              733.76 |      15907.616 |       4.61
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=58b1670a7159be0a7ee5309834fd0424)*

Comment: If I wanted to move the Stock price out of this table and into another, how would I reference it? Here is the query I am trying: SELECT
`Stock`,
ROUND(SUM(`Stock_Price` * `Shares_Owned`),3) AS Aggregate_Value
,Total_Added_Up, ROUND((SUM(`StockInfo.Stock_Price` * `Shares_Owned`) / Total_Added_Up) * 100,3) as 'Exposure %'
FROM Trades, StockInfo CROSS JOIN (SELECT ROUND(SUM(`StockInfo.Stock_Price` * `Trades.Shares_Owned`),3) Total_Added_Up  FROM Trades, StockInfo)
GROUP BY `Stock`
ORDER BY `Exposure %` DESC;